# SSL connection using requests module

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I have installed SSL certificate in my apache2 and it works fine from the browser.

```
SSLCertificateFile /root/ca/intermediate/certs/www.example.com.cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/ca/intermediate/private/www.example.com.key.pem    
SSLCertificateChainFile /root/ca/intermediate/certs/ca-chain.cert.pem
```

Now, Im trying to connect to this server using python requests module using the same certificate that I gave in the **SSLCertificateFile** above.

```
import requests
r  = requests.get('https://localhost',verify='/Users/p/Documents/b/docker_images/vnet-creds/ca/intermediate/certs/www.example.com.cert.pem')
print r.status_code
print r.text
```

but still get the following error.

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)
[Finished in 0.3s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/p/Documents/b/docker_images/test_pki_certs/test.py"]


Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 4096 (0x1000)
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=GB, ST=England, O=B, OU=B Root, CN=B Root
        Validity
            Not Before: Jun 23 20:39:51 2017 GMT
            Not After : Jun 21 20:39:51 2027 GMT
        Subject: C=GB, ST=England, O=B, OU=B Root, CN=B Root inter
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
            RSA Public Key: (4096 bit)
                Modulus (4096 bit):
                    00:c0:5a:06:d1:7d:19:97:32:38:a1:fb:61:47:dd:
                    7b:89:a8:3d:25:ca:c9:28:f5:6c:e8:dd:02:20:cb:
                    74:f2:08:df:ec:92:54:cb:fe:5f:6b:35:45:7f:9b:
                    0c:27:13:a1:74:28:ff:af:1f:5a:55:9d:64:04:bc:
                    c7:2f:cd:43:51:ee:82:b6:cf:e3:c4:e7:90:07:c8:
                    4a:55:b4:5f:47:9c:33:e6:bc:4c:e6:e7:04:5d:84:
                    b7:eb:01:60:6a:31:4d:2a:da:4b:f6:7c:84:82:7d:
                    3f:bf:f0:81:ee:6a:ab:aa:1a:9e:eb:81:c7:b8:76:
                    f9:0d:f8:c6:a2:89:9e:6c:4c:6b:1c:47:91:f5:4d:
                    3c:26:71:c7:16:51:f8:a6:06:bc:0e:8d:b8:a0:7f:
                    86:73:c0:5b:65:3e:91:4c:44:6a:c6:45:03:7c:cf:
                    d2:13:6f:52:c7:a7:54:5d:8c:b7:3e:d1:c3:4c:dc:
                    68:42:ae:8b:0d:8e:55:41:cb:b5:25:2a:54:8b:7d:
                    53:86:8f:bb:8d:8d:03:cb:8f:42:b6:a0:6e:ce:63:
                    ec:24:ce:fa:e4:7a:66:bb:ff:94:65:57:14:70:ba:
                    f3:eb:a5:a6:d9:f4:81:01:2f:7f:a6:1e:12:b7:0f:
                    b4:71:a2:3f:11:6b:b5:af:0f:51:78:a0:31:8b:b9:
                    f3:38:99:89:bf:d4:1f:14:3e:c5:ce:71:44:86:a1:
                    05:b1:db:6a:dc:31:8c:4f:91:3c:c7:50:77:b2:f5:
                    e8:83:e6:bb:76:ee:f6:25:05:bc:2a:3b:6d:fe:1e:
                    9d:14:4b:d2:f5:ea:ae:b4:ef:b8:ae:73:16:4b:b1:
                    67:6b:5a:8b:ef:59:a3:b5:14:13:30:41:2c:85:51:
                    7e:70:3f:92:ed:dc:14:80:92:a9:67:b2:58:10:ce:
                    91:d0:96:cc:3f:46:8a:16:2c:5b:c4:a0:5d:c8:69:
                    65:43:f6:9e:d1:8f:25:4b:42:3c:e1:eb:5d:eb:f6:
                    85:3f:e2:27:9f:ed:63:84:4a:19:ec:07:ee:9c:46:
                    14:66:f1:aa:22:15:93:87:48:1f:a2:fe:fb:81:9b:
                    3f:aa:55:a9:98:0f:ba:0a:4e:0a:df:02:89:73:2c:
                    92:7d:63:1b:61:59:de:a5:bd:1e:1c:f0:c7:84:88:
                    50:4e:9c:93:26:bd:5b:45:07:b6:0d:13:c4:32:ec:
                    e3:52:e8:84:0c:37:c5:5d:a8:f5:bd:b6:68:35:9e:
                    3d:60:0c:67:cb:94:3a:39:89:e6:28:2f:67:dc:ce:
                    ba:a1:e1:4e:22:e1:ee:cc:b9:12:99:2d:96:ae:fc:
                    dc:a6:cf:2b:7b:88:58:2b:56:10:f8:fe:f1:d9:c3:
                    e8:82:11
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                E8:6B:7F:00:5C:2A:29:CE:59:FE:92:64:C0:FF:EF:0D:BC:A2:C4:92
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:E0:B2:2B:B8:F3:7D:9B:0A:76:00:CA:EB:87:8F:8A:32:89:3A:C2:EE

            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE, pathlen:0
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        7e:61:6c:4f:7a:42:ba:0f:f0:1e:df:71:ac:9a:36:b1:9f:f1:
        1d:8c:9f:c5:07:f4:16:56:f2:35:da:fc:23:ad:41:2b:44:cc:
        17:5f:f1:ac:d2:5f:af:77:c5:cb:71:35:56:c5:c2:a4:ff:64:
        b6:21:c1:dc:ed:06:72:d0:23:e6:25:22:56:15:4f:5b:94:86:
        7c:6c:f5:86:e0:6b:d5:dc:61:59:fe:92:9f:31:b5:58:48:08:
        46:62:c4:1b:0a:30:c7:ef:cb:c1:c9:a4:44:c6:18:d1:c3:f3:
        5c:6c:39:cd:a1:ce:56:f1:34:61:f4:1b:2d:53:a4:49:f6:aa:
        88:c1:84:bb:1e:42:27:42:79:ae:a3:4f:78:92:06:87:a2:9e:
        eb:a8:cd:a0:a4:25:5c:2f:55:f3:8a:93:26:49:de:ca:b7:fd:
        cd:9e:8b:13:e8:76:09:c9:fa:8c:14:9f:ee:67:05:80:e0:67:
        2d:54:e9:a6:ac:6b:87:34:d2:b5:11:23:fd:c0:67:c4:26:b1:
        2d:ae:0a:ca:ff:e6:86:9f:82:fc:9c:e1:10:1b:e1:61:b7:f2:
        3e:26:e8:1d:a8:76:9d:e0:fe:ca:28:f4:d0:b6:67:07:06:b1:
        56:ba:6e:ad:42:6c:8d:78:6c:eb:f8:1c:2d:75:f4:3f:92:d5:
        9d:ca:ac:0f:dc:6c:b3:4b:cb:9a:d6:be:e6:61:24:4f:90:be:
        c6:7c:61:86:8f:80:00:1e:66:b6:05:1a:f5:87:b8:c9:63:21:
        e6:c9:33:6d:1e:09:fa:91:c6:08:75:a5:2a:34:68:05:2d:d5:
        32:79:98:f6:6a:73:15:53:39:15:2c:e0:cf:05:7d:48:46:cf:
        bd:a5:d5:ab:6f:e8:0d:43:64:9c:eb:da:c3:d5:ab:56:15:76:
        0d:8b:2a:56:59:82:26:3c:9c:74:9e:0f:b2:71:95:8a:1e:4e:
        89:82:1c:15:48:12:a2:8f:88:8b:f4:d7:e0:39:50:da:5a:2c:
        19:44:2e:27:81:91:cd:79:b9:51:cd:38:f1:35:db:36:00:89:
        e9:74:ef:b8:15:84:31:32:bd:b4:c4:dd:29:d1:d2:e9:96:52:
        a0:b4:c5:ed:71:c8:4d:11:c4:4d:67:7c:a0:05:35:30:5f:ce:
        18:de:5d:a4:09:9e:29:73:f4:43:54:76:5c:3e:b2:d6:f5:ce:
        e0:31:93:c2:fe:aa:d6:f3:14:8e:50:b0:82:ca:a6:cb:91:e5:
        1c:f2:31:9c:09:81:f7:e3:4f:93:8c:46:84:27:89:c1:0a:2c:
        03:46:26:a5:f5:52:e4:0e:d4:e2:a6:7f:8f:9c:a3:ef:61:45:
        4f:76:ff:66:80:57:c6:01
```

Comment: It is unknown what the contents of all the files is you gave not is the python version and apache version known. Thus one cannot reproduce your problem. But, the `verify` parameter should point to a file containing the root CA and the chain file should include all certificate which are needed to build the trust chain from the leaf certificate to the given root CA - in the right order. And of course the name given in the URL should match the name in the certificate. Also note that [SSLCertificateChainFile is deprecated](https://serverfault.com/questions/588986/) and thus might not work.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: Thanks..I removed SSLCertificateChainFile and my web requests are still working fine, that means the webserver setup is correct for SSLCertificateFile, SSLCertificateKeyFile. The SSLCertificateChainFile contains all the chained certs. When I pass that, still I get the same error.

Comment: I have provided the contents of my file.Its python2.7 and its apache2

Comment: ALso, this is a self signed certificate.

Comment: Please specify the exact versions, i.e. python 2.7.XX and apache2.XX.YY. Also, the content of the file given to the verify parameter is still unknown and is still unknown if the name in the URL matches the certificate. And you probably mean a certificate issued by your own CA and not self-signed, because a self-signed certificate is one which is signed by the same certificate itself. And, browsers usually cache intermediate certificates so it does not mean that all needed certificates are send by the server just because the browser throws no error.

Comment: Python 2.7.13 &  Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)..Can you elaborate more "content of the file given is still unknown". The file is present and I have given the contents of the file above...I used this site to generate my own self signed certificate...https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/sign-server-and-client-certificates.html...The certificates on the browser did work as I have to run few chrome commands to add it..By default it failed as it said its invalid certificate.

Comment: @user1050619 what exactly are you trying to do here? `requests` will auto-fail an https request for an invalid request anyway... If you're trying to do some testing against specific cert's, then read down carefully from http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification about what you need to do.

Comment: @user1050619: you had given the contents of the chain file (and removed it again). You had not given the content of the file which is used in the `verify` parameter - or if this was the same file then you did not say this (file names differ). And if the currently shown file is really the one you use in the `verify` parameter - then it is not the one you need because it is not the root CA (see my first comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, Im trying to connect to this server using python requests module using the same certificate that I gave in the SSLCertificateFile above.

The `verify` parameter expects trusted CA and not simply trusted certificates. The leaf certificate is not a CA certificate and thus will not be considered when building the trust chain. Instead you should give the root CA and, in case the server does not send the chain certificates, also the chain certificates needed to build the trust chain to the given root CA.

Apart from that make also sure that the subject(s) of the certificate match the domain name given in the URL.

Comment: I have a intermediate authority, in that case is it ok to give the intermediary CA instead of root CA?.. can you clarify if browser also downloads the root CA?

Comment: @user1050619: the browser does not download the root CA but you have to add the root CA as trusted to the browser. And at least with openssl (which is the backend for requests) it is not enough to only provide the intermediate certificate - it needs to have the root CA because it tries to use only root CA (i.e. signed by themselves) as trust anchor.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it well. I'll have it setup tomorrow and will let u know for any issues.

Comment: Also, I need to create a client certificate for authentication. Is it mandatory that for client auth to work first I need to build server authentication and then implement client auth.

Comment: @user1050619: server authentication is done to protect against man in the middle attacks which means you need some kind of server auth in all cases. So yes, you need server auth too even if you use client auth.

Comment: Ok, got it..is it technically possible to just implement client auth and not server auth?

Comment: I thought to implement client auth you need to enable SSL and to enable SSL means to implement server auth first, so technically I believe u need to enable server auth before implementing client auth.

Comment: @user1050619: you can of course have client auth with username and password w/o SSL but in this case the credentials are sent in clear. But given the context of the question I assumed that you are talking about client auth based on client certificates. Anyway - this is out of the context of the original question so please ask a new one.

Comment: @ Steffen Ullrich: Thanks , it worked. I opened a different question as well..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44751021/intermediate-root-authority-validation