# intermediate root authority cross chain validation

Tags: security, ssl, x509, pki

I have created a root CA(CA-R) and two intermediary CA's(CA-I1 & CAI2)(all self-signed).

Using CA-I1, I generated a private key for a server1/client1, CSR & created the certs. Installed the certs for Server1(Apache2) and client1.Im successfully able to connect to the server1 using my  client1(python client).

```
Here is the chain -> client1->server1->CA-I1->root CA
```

Using CA-I2, I generated a private key for a server2/client2, CSR & created the certs. Installed the certs for Server2(Apache2) and client2. Im successfully able to connect to the server2 using my  client2(python client).

```
Here is the chain -> client2->server2->CA-I2->root CA.
```

Now, I would like to know if using client2 can I connect to server1 by adding the certs of the CA-I1(as both CA-I1 & CA-I2 are from same Root CA)part of python client.
Basically want to know if I can cross chain authenticate.

Comment: Also see [“Countersigning” a CA with OpenSSL](https://serverfault.com/q/374343/145545) on Server Fault and [Cross-certification between worlds like X.509 and PGP?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/91392/29925) on InfoSec.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is the chain -> client1->server1->CA-I1->root CA

I hope you did not sign the client certificates with the server certificates as your question suggests but that you signed the client certificates with the CA certificates (i.e. CA-I1, CA-I2). Otherwise this would only work if the server certificate would be both used as a leaf certificate for server authentication and as a CA certificate to sign the client certificate. These different kinds of use cases are better not merged into a single certificate. Thus what you should actually use is:

```
   server1 -> CA-I1 -> root-CA
   client1 -> CA-I1 -> root-CA
   server2 -> CA-I2 -> root-CA
   client2 -> CA-I2 -> root-CA
```

> ... if using client2 can I connect to server1 by adding the certs of the CA-I1(as both CA-I1 & CA-I2 are from same Root CA)part of python client

Each client and server can trust several CA and the certificates used for client and server certificate validation can actually be different. But, considering that server1 trusts any certificate signed by root-CA for client authentication it will trust both client1 and client2, providing that all intermediate certificates needed to build the trust chain to root-CA are sent by the client together with the leaf certificate. This is not different from server authentication.

Comment: Thanks @Steffen..Its working as you mentioned..Is there a way to limit to say that "server1 do not trust certificates with other intermediaries"?

Comment: @user1050619: you might try [SSLRequire](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslrequire) or [Require](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#reqexpr) together with `SSL_CLIENT_I_*` [Environment Variables](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#envvars) to limit the issuer of the certificate to a specific one.

Comment: ok, thank..will check on that..Not sure if my understanding is right but its weird for me to think that a user(U1)  under intermediary CA(CA1) can cross authenticate another server(S2) under intermediary CA(CA2) just because both are under the same root CA. I'm imagining how it works in big companies where they have multiple division. Should everyone have a different root CA?

Comment: @user1050619: while it might be useful to  have only CA-I1 or CA-I2 as trust anchor my experience with the OpenSSL stack suggests that it always needs to have a root-CA (i.e. self-signed which means signed with the key inside the same certificate) as final trust anchor.

Comment: Thanks. What happens if I have 2 intermediate CA(same root) on different servers with different user certs generated. The users will have access to trust chain and can accesses apps in both these servers. Now, one user been revoked on one server, how will be notified to other server to revoke his access.

Comment: @user1050619: certificate revocation is not done "on a server" but distributed using CRL or OCSP. But - this moves away from your original question so please ask a new one instead. And, security.stackexchange.com might be a better place for this kind of questions.

Comment: Thanks, opened a new one...https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/162878/common-root-ca-with-multiple-intermediate-ca-on-different-server

Comment: Also, as per this link https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/139135/will-two-intermediate-cas-signed-by-the-same-root-ca-trust-each-others-signed-c   , you had mentioned that "If service A trusts only intermediate A but not the root CA then it will trust any certificates signed with intermediate A but no certificates signed with intermediate B because no trust chain can be built from intermediate A to certificates signed by intermediate B"...How can I ask server A to trust only intermediate A?